# bind (TwoWay) string to two radio buttons with content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, two-way-binding

I want to bind (TwoWay) a string value ("True" or "False") to two radio buttons with Content "True" and "False".

**Conditions**

1. When use select "True" RadioButton , string value should be "True" and vice versa for "False" radio button.
2. At a time only one RadioButton is selectable either True or False.
3. There is list of string and Radio Buttons are part of DataTemplate.

**XAML**

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton x:Name="rbTrue" Content="True" IsChecked="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="rbFalse" Content="False" IsChecked="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="rbTrue" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="rbFalse" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="rbTrue" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="rbFalse" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel viewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class MainViewModel : ModelBase
{
    private List<MainModel> values;
    public List<MainModel> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return values;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != values)
            {
                values = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Values");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Values = new List<MainModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                Values.Add(new MainModel() { Value = true });
            else
                Values.Add(new MainModel() { Value = false });
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class MainModel : ModelBase
{
    private bool strValue;
    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            return strValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != strValue)
            {
                strValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MODELBASE**

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

**UI**

[image]

I almost tried everything I know and also checked most of the relative links online on different forum and other material.

All I want is value either "True" or "False" based in user selection in list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to use a single ToggleButton or CheckBox?

Comment: @Clemens I need to use radio buttons only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you meant "bind (TwoWay) *Boolean* value to two radio buttons" instead of "bind (TwoWay) *string* to two radio buttons", since `Value` has the data type `bool`.

First, do not use the `DataTrigger`s; remove them.

Instead, on the binding for the "false" button, add a converter that negates the boolean value:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rbFalse" Content="False" IsChecked="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource NegateConverter}}"/>
```

In your XAML resources, you need to define the converter:

```
<local:NegateConverter x:Key="NegateConverter"/>
```

Replace `local` by whatever namespace you defined the `NegateConverter` class in.

Here is the code for the converter:

```
/// <summary>
/// This converter negates a boolean value.
/// </summary>
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class NegateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bValue = (bool)value;
        }
        return !bValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bValue = (bool)value;
        }
        return !bValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your converter code really helped me. I wanted this only but for string. I modified it.